# How to display default tab using jQuery - manual coding for Tabs, not jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, default

I coded my tab structure manually, and it doesn't exactly follow the jQuery UI default Tabs structure. Now I want to display the First tab as the default tab on page load, but this does not seem to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="tabNavi">
            <li><a href="#tabs_1">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs_2">Tab2</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs_1"></div>
        <div id="tabs_2" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code I used is as follows:

```
tabnone: function(){
    $('#tabs ul.tabNavi li a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        var divIDS = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,10);
        var divID = divIDS.split(',');
        $('div#'+divID).slideUp(25);
    });
},

setupNavigation: function() {
    $('#tabs ul.tabNavi li a').each(function(){
        var divIDS = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,10);
        var divID = divIDS.split(',');
        $('div#'+divID).hide();
    });

    $('#tabs ul.tabNavi li a').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            var divIDS = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,10);
            var divID = divIDS.split(',');
            $('div#'+divID).slideDown(250);
        }
    });

    $('#tabs ul.tabNavi li a').ready(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var divContent = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,10);
            var div_ID = divContent.split(',');
            // Show the div
            alert(div_ID);
            $('div#'+div_ID).show();
            $('div#'+div_ID).slideDown(250);
        }
     });

     $('#tabs ul.tabNavi li a').click(function(){
         if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
             GATECore.Pages.IndexHelper.tabnone();
             $(this).addClass('active');
             var divContent = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,10);
             var div_ID = divContent.split(',');
             // Show the div
             $('div#'+div_ID).show();
             $('div#'+div_ID).slideDown(250);
         }
    });
}
```